# Calling the service asynchronously in the GridValidating event

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

In the Telerik GridValidating event , I would like to make a service call asynchronously. How would I validate the grid when the data coming back is asynchronous. Please help.
I am using Silverlight MVVM pattern.The validating event is in the ViewModel and the call to service is done in another class( Model)

Comment: in mvvm serviceagent is one concept that can remove dependency injection you have to try this concept.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_mvvm_topic2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this [RowValidation](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/RowValidation) example on Telerik's online demo site?